# How to group and sum at the same time with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
Year    Age     Count
1999    0       80
        1       80
        2       80
        3       80
        4       90
        5       100
        ...
2000    0       60
        ....
```

I would like to group the ages in different ranges, such as [0,5), [5, 10), ... and get the associated totals for those ranges. So the above would become

```
Year    Age     Count
1999    0-4     410
        5-9     ...
        ...
2000    0-4     ...
        ...
```

Is there a simple way to do this with a `groupby` and a `sum`?

Comment: Maybe... can you add some code to reproduce this dataset please?

Comment: Use [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) (as @MaxU suggests) to make an intermediate `Age_Range` column:

```
cut_points = range(0, df.Age.max() + 5, 5)
df['Age_Range'] = pd.cut(df.Age, cut_points)
df.groupby(['Year', 'Age_Range'])['Count'].sum()
```

The `range()` function creates the cut points for `pd.cut()`, between 0 and your maximum value, plus five, in increments of five.